# Get email of the Rails app administrator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, administrator

How do I get the email address of the app owner in Rails?

Django has `ADMINS` setting in the configuration file that stores exactly that:

```
ADMINS = [('John', 'john@example.com'), ('Mary', 'mary@example.com')]
```

Is there something similar in the Rails world? I'm making a gem that needs to notify app's owner and I wouldn't want to add my own initializer if there's already a way.

Answer (score -1):

Yep you can do it.. check it out here:
http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'hola'
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.date        = '2010-04-28'
  s.summary     = "Hola!"
  s.description = "A simple hello world gem"
  s.authors     = ["Nick Quaranto"]
  s.email       = 'nick@quaran.to'
  s.files       = ["lib/hola.rb"]
  s.homepage    =
    'http://rubygems.org/gems/hola'
  s.license       = 'MIT'
end
```